# Admob iOS: Getting com.google.DummyAdapter on real device, works on simulator

Tags: ios, admob

I am having this issue with Admob:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s):
>   ("com.google.DummyAdapter"). Remember to link all required ad network
>   adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting
>   of your build target.

I have read that this could be due to a "no-fill" problem when asking for a network adapter, but this is happening to me only if I try on a real device. If I try it on the simulator, I receive the ads correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this is happening when you have the device as a test device.. It's happening to me as well. Did you manage to fix the problem?

Comment: I am still having that issue, but the ads are shown correctly, so I don't really know what the problem is.

Comment: I do have the flag -ObjC still same issue.

Comment: do u find a solution ?

Comment: @Jack I can't really remember how I solved it, but try to use the latest pods of Google Admob

Comment: i did and still getting same error in your question :/ i hope u remember how to solve it and save my day :D

Answer (score 3):

```
Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): com.google.DummyAdapter. Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.
```

If you faced with the error above, consider the options below:

- There were *no ads to be served from any of the networks* in the mediation stack.
- There are no ads to show in your country or region (If so try via VPN). This would include the AdMob network.
- it might just be an issue with your account. Also, please double check your Ad Unit ID. You can try with another account (Ad Unit ID) to be sure about your implementation.

Best

Comment: Is this your experience when you write "usually indicates" or did Google (AdMob) mention that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, probably my experience, first I couldn't remember, but now I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I fixed in a weird way. I read that some people where having this issue due to eCPM being to high or something like that. So, I went to my AdMob configuration to check it and everything seemed fine, but just in case I re-save the settings and violá, ads starting to work again.

This is the steps that I made:

- Go to AdMob administration
- Click on Monetize tab
- Click on your problematic app
- On the ad block, click on the link on the mediation column
- Click on AdMod Network
- Don't change anything, save data again

Hope this works for somebody...

Comment: I basically did this, but also tried lowering the eCPM floor to a small value. Then, let it run a while before bringing the value back up to a higher price.

Answer (score 2):

**THIS WORKED FOR ME:**

Just make sure that **"Limit Ad Tracking"** is **"turned off"** in your **iPhone's settings** under `Privacy > Advertising.` 
And try to `Reset your Advertising Identifier.`

Comment: Well this is not really helpful since we don't want to tell that each person which downloaded our app.

Answer (score 2):

THIS MAY BE HELPFUL FOR SOMEONE!!!

I got the same error when I used the Ad Unit Ids defined in the AdMob app for testing on my iPhone. Of course the device has to be registered as a Test Device. I was adding the Test Device Id programmatically.

This is where I went a wrong route. The documents has clearly mentioned steps on how to register a device as a Test Device. Instead all that I somehow made my mind to register the device's UDID as the Test Device Id(*This is the mistake I made. Now I accept that it is purely my ignorance*). After searching through most of the solutions provided in SO, and some of the other blogs, I just wanted to try the AdMob UI to add a test device. There I saw **Advertising ID/IDFA** which had a link on how to find the advertising ID/IDFA.

```
AdMob -> Settings -> Test Devices -> Add Test Device
```

Just to reiterate the steps which fixed the issue for me:

1. Take/copy the Ad Unit Ids which you defined in your AdMob app
2. Put those Ad Unit Ids in your code.(I used **xcconfig** files to separate **Dev vs Prod**)
3. Run the app by now you might have setup all your ad plugging code
4. **Check the Xcode console**(important), there you will see the Test Device Id suggested by Google. Which will look something like below:

   **<Google*>* To get test ads on this device, set:
   GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ @"**2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b**" ]; // Pay attention at this bolded id, this is the one which we want.
5. The above code is in Obj-C. Use the below code in Swift 5+

   **GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]**

---

**Take away**: Test Device Identifier is **not UDID** of the device but the **Advertising Identifier**. Check this: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433?hl=en#ID

---

**Tip:** I used the **Dev.xcconfig** file to add the Test Device identifiers, so that the **Prod.xcconfig** is clean without those test device ids and the app can be submitted without any code changes.

```
 /// Extract those test device ids from the xcconfig file.
 if let testIDs = self.extractTestDeviceIDs() {
    debugPrint("FOUND: test IDs: ", testIDs)
    GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = testIDs
 } else {
    debugPrint("NOT FOUND: test IDs")
    /// NoOp: This has to be prod environment
    /// If the test IDs are not configured, then also Ads should be initialized.
 }

 GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start { initStatus in
    debugPrint("GAD Ads... Init Status: ", initStatus)
 }
```

Comment: You are a life saver! After setting IDFA in AdMob, test ads (real) start to come.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error "Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): ("com.google.DummyAdapter")." when i tried to implement a rewarded ad, when i had only a banner ad configured in Admob.

After adding a rewarded ad to admob for the app, the error disapeared.

Answer (score 0):

here is what problem we had. initially we used the same app id and add id for android and ios. Later we thought to analyze them separately and hence created a new ios Add app and created a new add. now in the code we added the newly created add for ios. However we forgot to update the info.plist with the new app id.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential reason:

> Caution: If you set up an `app-ads.txt` file for your app, you need to
> also include this line in your app-ads.txt file in order to load ads
> using the demo ad units:
>
> `google.com, pub-3940256099942544, DIRECT, f08c47fec0942fa0`
>
> Alternatively, you can enable test devices and use your own ad unit IDs instead.

Source: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads#enable_test_devices

Answer (score -1):

Try Setting Other Linker Flags as -ObjC in Linking section of Build Settings.

Comment: The flag is set. That is not the problem.