# AdMob not serving ads on iOS release. Error code 8, Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): ("com.google.DummyAdapter")

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

Whenever I try to load an ad on the release version of my iOS app, I get the following admob error:

> Cannot find an ad network adapter with the name(s): ("com.google.DummyAdapter"). Remember to link all required ad network adapters and SDKs, and set -ObjC in the 'Other Linker Flags' setting of your build target.

I'm using the google_mobile_ads 0.13.0 package in my flutter 2.2.1 project. Ads are displaying correctly on the android version of the app and I'm getting test ads from these units in the iOS simulator.

So far I've tried:

- Setting the "-ObjC" flag under Other Linker Flags in the linking section of build settings
- Limit ad tracking is off, there is no such option on the iPad I'm using.
- Add the iAd.framework to Link Binary With Libraries in Build Phases
- Add the io.flutter.embedded_views_preview key to info.plist
- I've followed the setup instructions on the pub.dev page of [google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)
- I'm using the correct unit and app ids, configured for iOS.
- Sufficient time has passed since the creation of the ad unit for it to start serving ads

used links :

- [limit ad tracking/ -ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222185/admob-ios-getting-com-google-dummyadapter-on-real-device-works-on-simulator)

The ad units are currently being used by an app in the app store, whereas this project is being tested on testflight. I'm not sure if this has any effect on it, seeing how ads are working fine for android which also uses units that are being used by an active app. Changing the eCPM is not an option as the ads are currently being used in a different live app. But this would raise the same question as to why it is working for android and the other live iOS app.

I'm still too new to iOS development to know what could cause this error and I would very much appreciate any help in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your Phone as test device in Google Admob over at the Settings. Then it should work! When releasing to play store make sure to state that your app is using Ads in the console

[LoadAdError(code: 3, domain: com.google.android.gms.ads, message: No ad config... when trying to load BannerAd in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68209488/loadaderrorcode-3-domain-com-google-android-gms-ads-message-no-ad-config)